# I tried many methods for decipher but none of them worked

Tags: node.js, encryption, node-crypto

I need to encrypt and decrypt files for the application I am developing. I also use Node.js' built-in crypto package for this. When I try in variables, I can encrypt/decrypt a text, but whenever it's time to encrypt/decrypt files, decipher causes problems. I really did a lot of research before posting here but nothing worked properly. My `key` and `iv` values are fixed 32 byte and 16 byte values respectively. Here is my code:

```js
const encryptFile = (inputPath, outputPath) => {
    const input = fs.createReadStream(inputPath)
    const output = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath)
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv)

    input.on('data', data => {
        const encryptedData = cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'hex')
        output.write(encryptedData)
    })

    input.on('end', () => {
        const encryptedData = cipher.final('hex')
        output.write(encryptedData)
        output.end()
    })
}

const decryptFile = (inputPath, outputPath) => {
    const input = fs.createReadStream(inputPath)
    const output = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath)
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv)
    decipher.setAutoPadding(false)

    input.on('data', data => {
        const decryptedData = decipher.update(data, 'hex', 'utf8')
        output.write(decryptedData)
    })

    input.on('end', () => {
        const decryptedData = decipher.final('utf8')
        output.write(decryptedData)
        output.end()
    })
}
```

And I run them respectively as follows: (After running the first one, I comment it out and run the second one, there is no problem here.)

```js
encryptFile('test.txt', 'test_encrypted.txt')
decryptFile('test_encrypted.txt', 'test_decrypted.txt')
```

Content of test.txt:

```
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Content of test_encrypted.txt: (After running `encryptFile()`)

```
44e481b3b6dbc1276860122a9256838d0f3a717f31308e0223d5d995d5929566
```

Content of test_decrypted.txt: (After running `decryptFile()`)
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf5bC.png)

I tried my code, I did research from many places on the internet, but I couldn't get it to work. I want my code to properly encrypt/decrypt the file I want.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deleting the last parameters I gave to the `.update()` and `.final()` methods and `decipher.setAutoPadding(false)`.